# Why this TextViews are not showing when I run into a real device or emulator

Tags: android, dashboard, android-gridlayout, android-designer

Hello guys I have designed a GridLayout with CardViews to make a Dashboard but  the TextViews of the items are not showing in the emulator and a real device.. in the designer view it are showing but when I run it those TextView are not showing.. what could happen?
Here is my blueprint view:
[image]
And this is the UI design:

[image]
as we can see the textview if they are showing in the user interface..
Here is my code of the xml layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:background="@drawable/header_background2"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textGrid"
        android:text="GRID LAYOUT"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <!--  Row 1 -->
            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/chartDiet"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/diet" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Dieta"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/chartExercise"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/exercise" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Exercise"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!--  Row 2 -->
            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/chartMeditation"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/meditation" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Meditation"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/chartYoga"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/yoga" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Yoga"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!--  Row 3 -->

        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/chartRunning"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/running" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Running"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/chartWorkout"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/workout"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Workout"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Someone can help me i don't know where is the error.. or i have a bad design and maybe I should start again with another project using ConstraintLayout like root element..
thanks..
PD: the code for every row is the same only change the image and textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is working on my emulator
my dependency in `build.gradle` is 
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
please try to change to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textGrid"
            android:text="GRID LAYOUT"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <!--  Row 1 -->
        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/chartDiet"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_collections_bookmark_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Dieta"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/chartExercise"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_collections_bookmark_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Exercise"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!--  Row 2 -->
        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/chartMeditation"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_collections_bookmark_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Meditation"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/chartYoga"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_collections_bookmark_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Yoga"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!--  Row 3 -->

        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/chartRunning"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_collections_bookmark_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Running"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/chartWorkout"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_collections_bookmark_black_24dp" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Workout"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

with build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.something"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

}
```

Also I do not know your drawables, check also that they do not have a black background, if still does not work

Comment: I tryed 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0' and 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3' but it doesn't work.. the IDE says:  version 28 (intended for android pie and below) is the last version of the legacy support library.. this message is to Migrate to androidx.. I thought I had a design error but is by the version of cardview.. i don´t know how to fix it using androidx